# Selenium unable to locate element despite adding time.sleep()

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I wrote a script to find and click a button and it worked fine until today. I wonder what is causing:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[data-bind="click:selectLocation"]"}
```

I have tried adding time.sleep() just to make sure that I am waiting enough for the page to load but no, the error still shows up. Here is the html of the button:

```html
<div class="form-group">                    
 <div class="col-xs-12">                       
   <label data-bind="lang:searchSelectLocation">Select a location</label>                        
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block text-left" data-bind="click:selectLocation">                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker-alt" data-bind="css:loadingLocation ? 'fa-spinner fa-spin' : 'fa-map-marker-alt'"></i>&nbsp;<!--ko text: location ? location.name : $root.lang('searchSelectLocationOptions') -->Cityname<!--/ko--><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i>                        
  </button>                  
 </div>               
</div>
```

And here is the code snippet to find and click the button:

```
time.sleep(20)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[data-bind="click:selectLocation"]').click()
time.sleep(20)
```

**P.S I already had a wait before clicking as well. Sorry for missing it.**

Comment: You need to sleep before looking for it. time.sleep() then driver.find()

Comment: As already suggested put any wait before clicking. 200 seconds is too big timeout

Comment: I do have a time.sleep() before as well. Does not help.

Comment: @DanMullin Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Jandeer7 I’ve been looking. I use the .Net version of Selenium and have been successful with using the wait until loaded function. Is that in python Selenium? I see that it is based on the answer. Hmmm..

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you should be waiting *before* you click the button, not afterwards, to ensure that it is loaded.

Secondly, Selenium comes with so-called [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) that allow you to wait until an element is visible or clickable.

So in your case, this would look like this:

```
max_time_to_wait = 200 # if it doesn't find the element in this timespan, it will throw a TimeoutException
element = WebDriverWait(driver, max_time_to_wait).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-bind="click:selectLocation"]')))
element.click()
```

Comment: Already had a wait before clicking but replaced with your suggestion but still got the exception after 200 timeout. Very strange

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome, hit Ctrl + Shift + I to inspect the webpage and after hitting Crtl + F you can type in your css selector. The button should be highlighted green if the selector is correct.

Comment: Yeah I did that and the button is there and highlighted as expected. That is why it is really strange

Comment: Okay, that's indeed very strange. It could also be inside an iframe. Can you send the link to the website?

Comment: Sure, can we talk in a chat directly? Thanks

Comment: For sure, you can contact me on Twitter, look at my profile.

Comment: Followed you. Follow back so I can DM